# building dynamically multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build dynamically a multidimensional array in PHP. I have a structure with categories, sub-categories, sub-sub-categories and so on. I am storing in MariaDB on each record, a string who gives me the path to that sub-sub-categories and storing the array in another table serializing that array

I built the push in array command dynamically, but it doesn't execute it like a command.
What i want is to build the command dynamically $arr[key1][key2][key3] and so on and insert a value (it doesn't matter the value, all that i am interrested too is the key) into that array

Thank you

```
  $sel_arr="SELECT * FROM arr_categ WHERE is_activ=1";
  $res_arr=mysqli_query($conn,$sel_arr);
  $rez_arr=mysqli_fetch_object($res_arr);
  $id_arr=$rez_arr->id;
  if($rez_arr->nume=='xxx'){
    $arr=array();
  } else {
    $arr=unserialize($rez_arr->nume);
  }

  if(isset($_POST["save_c"])){
    $id_categ=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["id_categ"]);
    $nume_c=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["nume_c"]);
    if($id_categ==0){
      $ins="INSERT INTO categ (nume, id_ordine, id_parinte, string) VALUES ('$nume_c', '1', '0', '0')";
      mysqli_query($conn,$ins);
      $id_c=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
      $arr[$id_c]=array();
      print_r($arr);
      $arr_ser=serialize($arr);
      $upd_arr="UPDATE arr_categ SET nume='$arr_ser' WHERE id='$id_arr'";
      mysqli_query($conn,$upd_arr);

    } else {
      $sel_cat="SELECT * FROM categ WHERE id='$id_categ'";
      $res_cat=mysqli_query($conn,$sel_cat);
      $nr_cat=mysqli_num_rows($res_cat);
      if($nr_cat==1){
        $rez_cat=mysqli_fetch_object($res_cat);        
        $id_ordine=$rez_cat->id_ordine+1;
        $id_parinte=$rez_cat->id_parinte+1;
        if($rez_cat->string==0){
          $string=$id_categ;
        } else {
          $string=$rez_cat->string.','.$rez_cat->id;
        }
        $ins_cat="INSERT INTO categ (nume, id_ordine, id_parinte, string) VALUES ('$nume_c', '$id_ordine', '$id_parinte', '$string')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$ins_cat);
        $id_cat=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $arr_string=explode(",",$string);
        $c=count($arr_string);
        foreach($arr_string as $item){
          $str.='['.$item.']';
        }
        $new_str='arr'.$str.'['.$id_cat.']';
        "$".$new_str=50;
        //$arr_ser=serialize($arr);
        //$upd_arr="UPDATE arr_categ SET nume='$arr_ser' WHERE id='$id_arr'";
        //echo $upd_arr.'<br>';
        //mysqli_query($conn,$upd_arr);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)